# How to know who can checkout my project in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can I know who can checkout my svn repository?

I have one project and team member are 4.

Can I know in 4 member who can checkout my project and who can not checkout my project?

Is possible in tortoise svn?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Can I know who can checkout my svn repository?

Yes

> Is possible in tortoise svn?

No. TortoiseSVN is client-side tool, your task is server-side